# Confusion about a simple Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was looking at a [table of Fourier transform pairs](https://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf), and one entry is really confusing me. There's one on the second page that states
$$
\mathcal{F}(\cos(\omega_0t))(\omega) = \pi(\delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0))
$$
I know that a Fourier transform is supposed to map a function in the time domain to an equivalent function in the frequency domain, so lets see what that means in this case. The period of $\cos(\omega_0t)$ is $2\pi/\omega_0$, meaning the frequency in rad/s is $\omega_0$. Thus at $\omega = \pm\omega_0$, the frequency domain should be $1$, because the amplitude of $\cos$ is $1$. When we plug it in, however, we get $\pi$:
$$
\pi(\delta(0) + \delta(2\omega_0)) = \pi(1 + 0) = \pi
$$
Why is this true? Isn't the amplitude of the cosine $1$, not $\pi$?

Comment: When you plug $\pm\omega_0$, you get "$\pi\infty$", if that makes sense. And with the usual convention, the coefficient is $1/2$, not $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dirac distribution needs an integration to lead to finite values.

And that might also explain the factor $\pi$, because that integration is the inverse Fourier transformation and that might have a compensating factor in your case.

Your text lists
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \!\! F(\omega)\,e^{j\omega t}\, d\omega
$$

so this gives
$$
f(t) =
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \!\! \pi \left[
\delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0)  
\right] \, e^{j\omega t}\, d\omega
=
\frac{1}{2}\left[ e^{j\omega_0 t} + e^{-j\omega_0 t}\right]
= \cos(\omega_0 t)
$$
so we could read the transform as
$$
F(\omega) = 
2\pi \, \frac{1}{2} \left[
\delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0)  
\right]
$$
where the $2\pi$ is due to the specific constants choosen for the Fourier transformation pair.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the Dirac delta function at zero would give you $\infty$. Remember that the Dirac delta is not, strictly speaking, a function, but rather a distribution. The Fourier transform gives the distribution of the function in the frequency domain, so the cosine function is made of of only two frequencies, with no spreading.

Comment: Yes that's weird, it only takes a value if you integrate it together with someone else. Like a function chameleon, a funchameleon.

Comment: I remember I asked my analysis professor if the set of integrable functions could be viewed as a commutative ring with identity under addition and convolution. He asked me what the identity was, I said the delta function. Then he told in no uncertain terms that the Dirac delta was NOT a function, and not to treat it like one.